# Crear un array con la cantidad de publicaciones por año de un custom post type

Tags: wordpress

Deseo crear un array con la cantidad de publicaciones que tengo por año de un custom post type llamado "papers" para alimentar un chart.

Se me ha sugerido usar wp_count_posts() pero ello solo me da la información del total de mi CPT.

Con get_archives() puedo tener la información pero es demasiado estática y no me permite crear ningún array.

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Ok, he tratado de hacerla más específica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien desea saber la respuesta, les comparto la traducción de la resolución que se me dio en el foro de Wordpress

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395928/get-an-array-of-the-number-of-post-per-year-of-a-custom-post-type-wordpress/396047#396047

```
// primero conseguimos todos los posts de tu CPT
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'      => 'papers', // basado en el CPT 
    'post_status'    => 'all',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
]);

// contendrá todos los post por año
// cada año contendrá las publicaciones contadas según su status (servicio extra =])
$posts_per_year = [];

// empecemos creando el loop
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // toma todos los años que tienen publicaciones
    $post_created_year = get_the_date('Y', $post);

    // revisa si el año existe en nuestro $posts_per_year
    // si no lo hace, lo agrega
    if (!isset($posts_per_year[$post_created_year])) {
        // añade el año, añade el status del post con la cifra inicial de 1 
        // (count)

        $posts_per_year[$post_created_year] = [
            $post->post_status => 1
        ];
    // el año ya existe, "adjunta" la cuenta a ese año
    } else {
        //revisa si el estatus ya existe en el año
        // si existe, añade +1 al valor 
        if (isset($posts_per_year[$post_created_year][$post->post_status])) {
            $posts_per_year[$post_created_year][$post->post_status] += 1;
        // no existe, añade el CPT al año con el valor inicial de 1 (count)
        } else {
            $posts_per_year[$post_created_year][$post->post_status] = 1;
        }
    }
}

// El código que sigue te permitirá ver el resultado de lo expresado 
// anteriormente.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($posts_per_year);
echo '</pre>';
```